# batch file CD and then run MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to create a batch file that opens command prompt, changes directory and then runs MySQL queries:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u admin -padmin -h localhost mydatabase
select * from table;
```

When I run the batch file the MySQL command line opens and connects to the database, but the select * from table; command doesnt run

```
select * from table;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch is not able to pass any line after the call of the exe to the program.

If you want to send a command you should create a textfile that contains the command. You can name it commands.txt

```
select * from table
```

Then tell mysql to read from that file:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u admin -padmin -h localhost mydatabase < commands.txt
```

If you need the results of the command, save them like that:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u admin -padmin -h localhost mydatabase < commands.txt > results.txt
```

You can read more about that approach [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).

Comment: my batch file is now: 
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u admin -padmin -h localhost mydatabase
mysql.exe < commands.txt - but the commands are not being executed